# Function not working when displaying time inside a div

Tags: javascript, function

### The idea is to display the time inside a *div* using the event handler *onload*, help appreciated.

Additional CSS is also included.

```
function currentTimeStrings(inp)
    var currentTime = new Date();
    {
        var ele = document.getElementById(inp);
        ele.innerHTML=currentTime;
    }
    
</script>
</head>
<body id="body" onload="currentTimeStrings('timeDisp')">

<div id="platform">
    <div id="mainOval">
        <div id="timeDisp">
        </div>
    </div>
        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is the date declared outside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced `{`, it should be after the function name and arguments

```
function currentTimeStrings(inp) {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var ele = document.getElementById(inp);
    ele.innerHTML = currentTime;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7he8U/)

In future, look at the console in the browser(f12 in chrome). this would have shown the syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var (index):32 Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: currentTimeStrings is not defined (index):19 onload

Comment: That might work but it's still not showing inside the div timedisp

Comment: @user3280654 Yes, it is. Use inspect element (f12) to check. [Here's a colored version](http://jsfiddle.net/7he8U/1/) to prove to you it's in the correct location